# How could I do a list from an AWS account listing all running instances?

Tags: windows-10, amazon-web-services, ansible, git-bash, public-key

I'm using AWSCLI at Windows 10 Professional with GitBash. I need to have a list of all running AWS instances by account. Will start doing in an account to make a list to populate the public keys from users.

Have based on these sites:

[Add SSH Key to EC2 instances with Ansible – Automated](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-ec2-ssh-key/)

AWS documentation:

[Filtering AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html)

And have done:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running
```

But the output from this command generate a lot of info. I tried to see the public IPs and generate a little less information, just to do a filtering test.

```
 $ aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --query NetworkInterfaces[].Association.PublicIp
[
    "5.1.210.2",
    "5.9.236.6",
    "5.25.225.6",
    "3.2.254.5",
    "3.9.237.67",
    "4.5.183.15",
    "8.6.37.159",
    "5.0.128.119",
    "5.8.74.231",
    "4.2.37.138",
    "5.8.103.63",
    "4.1.17.9",
    "4.4.216.193",
    "4.9.147.45",
    "4.7.169.22"
]
```

For security purposes I did a change at some octecs. Becomes a better output and I can't figure out how to filter in a right way the 1st example.

**My add-key.yml**

```
[root@devops list]# cat add-key.yml
- name: "Playbook to Add Key to EC2 Instances"
  hosts: hosts_to_add_key
  vars:
    - status : "present"
    - key : "user_rsa_key.pub"

  tasks:

  - name: "Copy the authorized key file from"
    authorized_key:
      user: "{{ansible_user}}"
      state: "{{status}}"
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ key }}')}}"
```

**My hosts_to_add_key:**

```
[root@devops list]# cat hosts_to_add_key
[hosts_to_add_key]
bacula ansible_host=3.2.1.43 ansible_user=centos
1.2.1.20 ansible_host=10.9.1.50 ansible_user=centos
devops ansible_host=localhost ansible_user=centos
docker ansible_host=52.87.108.170 ansible=ec2-user
jenkins ansible_host=52.7.6.214 ansible_user=ec2-user
jira ansible_host=54.175.104.102 ansible_user=ec2-user
[hosts_to_add_key:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
```

Removed some hosts above to show few lines. If someone could point me out about describe-instances to get better results will be fine (by name, by VPC)

Comment: Do you have a list of the AWS Accounts? Do you have access credentials in each of the AWS Accounts? You would need to call `describe_instances()` in each account (and in each region if applicable).

Comment: Yes I have for the major ones. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: I don't see why you would need to use SSH. If you have a list of AWS Accounts and a set of credentials for each account, you can write a script that loops through each account, them uses the credentials for that account to loop through each region and call `describe_instances()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting up aws cli:

1. Download and setup AWS CLI
2. Configure AWS i.e. `aws configure` (provide your account access key and secret key ID)
3. run the following code which lists the running instances along with the Private IP

   ```
    aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filter "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" \
    --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress, Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value|[0]]" \
    --output table > ec2_list.txt
   ```

This also outputs the table into the `ec2_list.txt` file which is good for sharing.